# Why is tangential acceleration always downward in this system?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation

Point A is rotating about an axis with angular velocity

$$w_0=w_i \hat{i} + w_k \hat{k}$$

and has position in the x-z plane

$$r=r_i \hat{i} + r_k \hat{k}$$

In addition, the angular velocity vector $w_0$ is precessing around

$$\Omega = \Omega_k \hat{k}$$

I can calculate the tangential acceleration using

$$\dot{\omega} \times r$$

which gives

$$r_k w_i \Omega_k \hat{i}-r_i w_i \Omega_k \hat{k}$$

Since $w_o$ and $r$ are both in the x-z plane, if there were no $\Omega$ then the tangential acceleration would be zero. Assuming all components are positive, introducing $\Omega$ seems to result in a tangential acceleration in the negative z-direction, irrespective of whether point A is at the "top" or the "bottom" of its spin when passing through the x-z plane, and I don't understand why.

How can this tangential acceleration always be negative in the z-direction, irrespective of choices of what positive values are chosen for $r_i$ and $w_i$?